# PHP e Javascript - Armazenamento de valor de checkbox escolhida (em session)

Tags: php, javascript, session, checkbox

Possuo na minha página algumas opções em checkboxes. Seriam opções de campanhas. Segue o código da tabela onde elas estão dispostas (linhas de três):

```
<table style="font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 20px" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
    <img id="imgCamp1" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 20px" src="images/campanhas/img0001.jpg" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick=window.open(src);>
    <br><input id="chkCamp1" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe(this)"> Campanha 1
</td>
<td>
    <img id="imgCamp2" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 20px" src="images/campanhas/img0002.jpg" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick=window.open(src);>
    <br><input id="chkCamp2" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe(this)"> Campanha 2
</td>
<td>
    <img id="imgCamp3" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 20px" src="images/campanhas/img0003.jpg" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick=window.open(src);>
    <br><input id="chkCamp3" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe(this)"> Campanha 3
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <img id="imgCamp4" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 20px" src="images/campanhas/img0004.jpg" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick=window.open(src);>
    <br><input id="chkCamp4" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe(this)"> Campanha 4
</td>
<td>
    <img id="imgCamp5" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 20px" src="images/campanhas/img0005.png" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick=window.open(src);>
    <br><input id="chkCamp5" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe(this)"> Campanha 5
</td>
<td>
    <img id="imgCamp6" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 20px" src="images/campanhas/img0006.png" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick=window.open(src);>
    <br><input id="chkCamp6" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe(this)"> Campanha 6
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
    <img id="imgCamp7" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 20px" src="images/campanhas/img0007.png" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick=window.open(src);>
    <br><input id="chkCamp7" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe(this)"> Campanha 7
</td>
<td>
    <img id="imgCamp8" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 20px" src="images/campanhas/img0003.jpg" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick=window.open(src);>
    <br><input id="chkCamp8" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe(this)"> Campanha 8
</td>
<td>
    <img id="imgCamp9" style="width: 280px; margin-top: 20px; margin-right: 20px" src="images/campanhas/img0001.jpg" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick=window.open(src);>
    <br><input id="chkCamp9" type="checkbox" class="cb" style="margin-left: -25px" onclick="showMe(this)"> Campanha 9
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

O código da página já está configurado para que somente uma opção possa ser selecionada. Contudo, o que eu preciso fazer é armazenar em uma variável (provavelmente uma de session) sempre o valor da checkbox escolhida (que eu acredito que valha 1).

Esse valor armazenado fará com que num e-mail posterior diga qual a campanha foi escolhida.

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on(click,function() {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

or

```
$('.cb').on(click,function() {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function showMe(element){
    alert(element.id);
}
```